# Real Time Data Extraction/ Transaction capturing

Tags: java, web-services, real-time

We are trying to capture some transactions on [near] Real-Time occuring on the Core-database, in another remote database connected via VPN. 
These transactions can be identified easily but we are facing challenge while deciding the workflow and identifying which technology to use.

For eg.
1.) Dumping CSV file every x seconds.
From the core system we create a CSV file every x seconds with the required information. We will then push/pull this file to the remote system and process it.

2.) Web Service
We will have 2 web services, one on the sender side & another on the reciever side. 
Every x seconds the sender web service will execute a query and fetch records from the source database and push the data to reciever web service in batches of 'y' records.
The receiver will then process the records and send an acknowledgement for 'y' records.

Note.

1.) Ideally we would like to make the process Real-Time. Both the above ideas are [near] Real-Time and not Real-Time.

2.) The source database system is not specific. It can be oracle,ms-sql,mysql,sybase,informix etc.

3.) Remote target database is oracle.

Any ideas are most welcome and also the technology used can be flexible.
The main focus is on decreasing the load caused due to this process on the core-database.

Edit:
It is becoming more and more clear to me that getting actual Real time with heterogeneous database systems will be nearly impossible as the trigger/notify on insertion of records are RDBMS specific.

I would like to shift the focus of the question to get better near Real time ideas apart from the above 2 examples shared.

Also please note that we have little to no control over the source database & also the process/service which originally inserts the records in the database. We only have control over the records.

Comment: The source DBMS will be important, not all DBs provide options to notify external applications of changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got what you are saying about the DBMS. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html) for an example on how to listen for database changes (in this case a database trigger) in PostgreSQL. Basically you set up a function to handle the trigger that sends an event to all interested clients. You Application will then listen for this event and can start the sync whenever the trigger is executed. The example applies the trigger to new insertions on a specific table.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Isn't this a viable solution to your problem? Your service will have to connect to the PostgreSQL database and can push changes to your Oracle Database/Web Service.

Comment: We don't have control over the source db & type. And as we are planning to extract from multiple sources the db is also variable.